# How can I make thinner Exclusions in Plot3D?

Tags: plotting

Consider this code:

```
Plot3D[Re[(x + I y)^(-1/2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
  PlotPoints -> 41,
  MaxRecursion -> 7, 
  ImageSize -> 900]
```

The exclusions line appears too thick to me: 3-4 pixels depending on orientation of the surface. How can I change its thickness? I'd like to have it about 1 pixel.

Comment: `ExclusionsStyle -> Thin`?

Comment: Beside the `ExclusionStyle`-option, it really helps to increase the PlotPoint count. (More Recursion do not really help here). So try `PlotPoints->400,MaxRecursion->1,ExclusionsStyle->AbsoluteThickness[10^-5]`

Comment: @Kuba I tried it, but for some reason I got strange colors of the exclusion instead of making the line thinner.

Comment: @JulienKluge `ExclusionsStyle`, same as in Kuba's comment, leads to some translucent bluish color of the exclusion instead of leaving it excluded and making it thinner. Using `Directive[AbsoluteThi‌ckness[10^-5],Opacity[0]]` just leaves the thickness as it was before.

Comment: You can also leave this blank. As I said, bigger PlotPoints-Option => smaller Exclusion gap (You can leave the MaxRecursion setting low though (1 is more than enough here)).

Comment: @JulienKluge well it does seem to make the exclusion just a bit thinner — about 1.5 times with `PlotPoints->800`. It doesn't seem to converge to zero or anything small, there seems to be a relatively large limit on the width. See [a screenshot](http://6g6.eu/sih-2-screenshot-031216-170044-png): above is with 800 points, below is result of the command in the OP. And anyway, using many plot points without recursion is a bad approach to plotting, since it makes the whole GUI unresponsive, and after some time I just got it to crash.

Comment: Well i sadly don't know how to solve this further. 
But for your unresponsive GUI. You can prerender the image with Rasterize. So it shouldn't lag anymore. (Use ViewPoint, etc. beforehand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if there's a native way to achieve what is requested. Here's how one can get this result manually. The exclusion lines will need to be found manually too in this case. The idea is to use `RegionFunction`, and disable any `Exclusions` completely.

In the following example the `0.005` part is what controls width of the custom exclusion.

```
Plot3D[Re[(x + I y)^(-1/2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 41, MaxRecursion -> 7, ImageSize -> 900,
 Exclusions -> None, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x > 0 || y^2 > 0.005^2]]
```